# Stdout looping halt after certain amount of characters

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want my program to have a looping display, which the code works, but the problem is that the character display is a long continuous line whereas I want it to go back to the start of the printing after a certain amount of characters have been displayed.

This is the entire code at this current moment:

```
import time
import sys



def Startup(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write( '%s' % c )
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.25)

def StartUpDot(s):

    while True:
        timeout = time.time() + 3*5
        Time = 0

        for c in s:
            sys.stdout.write( '%s' % c)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.25)
        if Time == 5 or time.time() > timeout:
            break
        Time = Time - 1

Startup("BOOTING UP"),
StartUpDot(".......") #This is what i want to repeat
```

The function that I want to do what I ask is the StartUpDot function. It instead displays a continuous line like "BOOTING UP................. etc"

To clarify I want the ...... to repeat from the start, the "BOOTING UP" is from a different function, i put the comma there to make it one line. I have it in a loop if that helps.

Sorry about the confusion

Comment: What do you mean by "go back to the start of the printing after a certain amount of characters have been displayed." ?

Comment: Do you want it to go to a new line underneath the old text, or be on the same line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

If you want the text to print out on the line below the current text, you need to print a `newline` character to stdout

```
sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

If you're using a maximum line width of 10 characters your output will look like this:

```
1 BOOTING UP
2 ........
```

If you want to clear the current text and print on the same line, you need to print a `carriage return` to stdout, which returns the cursor to the front of the line.  Then print empty space characters for the entire width of your line (to clear the old text), then another carriage return to return the cursor to the beginning of the line.

```
line_width = 10
sys.stdout.write('\r{0}\r'.format(' ' * line_width))
```

Using this method, the output would look like this (the line number is the same each time, so this is more like a time sequence).

```
1 BOOTING UP
1 OOTING UP.
1 OTING UP..
```

Here is an example

```
line_width = 10
for i in range(20):
    msg = 'BOOTING{0}'.format('.' * i)
    # Get only the last portion of the message
    # that is shorter than the line width
    msg = msg[-line_width:]
    # Pad with spaces if shorter than line width
    # Ensures old content is overwritten
    msg = msg.ljust(line_width)
    sys.stdout.write('\r{0}'.format(msg))
```

Comment: I added in what you suggested and i got this error

TypeError: 'PseudoOutputFile' object is not callable

Comment: Fixed.  Should be `sys.stdout.write()`, not `sys.stdout()`